# Python: Making my adventure game code, begin to "do something."

Tags: python

absolute beginner here. I am making a text adventure game to sharpen beginner skills. Can someone give me an example of what could go in my 
"def firstBattle", function?

Something like a small example of a battle, and updating the Stats and Inventory? Thanks

```
    def displayIntro():
        # I will update this as I think of more to add
        print(""" You are lord Deadra. You have been sent to Citiel to
              overthrow the current King Navator. Throughout your
              travels, you will encounter various enemies of all
              types. Good luck. """)


    def displayInventory():
    # Keeps a list of stuff in a dictionary. Because I returned 
    # stuff, I can use this function in other functions to update
        print("Inventory:")
        stuff = {"health potions": 5,
                 "poison": 5,
                 "stamina potions": 5,
                 "go crazy potion": 5,
                 "arrows": 50,
                 "hunting bow": 1,
                 "hunting knife": 1,
                 "big sword": 1,
                 "magic shield": 1}

        return stuff


    def displayStats():
    # Displays initial health stats
        print()
        print("Stats:")
        health = 100
        stamina = 100
        confidence = 100

        return "health:",health, "stamina:",stamina, "confidence:",confidence


    def firstBattle():
    # First encounter with an enemy. After battle, update inventory
    # and health stats
```

Comment: Does that not *strongly* depend on how you want your battles to work? I.e., a fixed or variable number of rounds, user interaction, random damage inflicted and so on?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Try to make your questions more concise. That way we can help you more

Comment: You should look into classes. This would be a perfect project to teach you about them. For example you could have an `adventurer` class that would contain the players stats and inventory inside of it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. This question isn't really a good fit for this site, because other than just writing your code for you, it's hard to know what a single self-contained answer would look like, rather than an extended discussion or tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'll keep plugging away

Comment: Agreed that these kinds of "Make a game" projects are perfectly suited to OOP. Learn to use the `class` keyword, make an `Actor`, and a `Player(Actor)`, and an `Item`, and an `Enemy(Actor)`, and etc.

Comment: Ok cool. I'll dig into learning about classes.

Comment: To follow up with your original question, once you followed @AdamSmith's advice, you'll probably want a generic "def battle(actor1, actor2)" function that can take 2 Actor instances and strictly perform the "maths" around your battle system (and return the winner, for instance). Then, you can just invoke it in "def firstBattle()" and other story-related functions to create your game script.

Answer (score 0):

You need a damage variable.
Implement an enemyDamage, enemyHealth and yourDamage variable.

```
def battleScene():
    print("ENTER to Attack.")
    input()
    health = health - enemyDamage
    enemyHealth = enemyHealth - yourDamage
    stamina = stamina - # What ever number you want stamina to go down
    print("Your HP: " + health)
    print("Enemy HP: " + enemyHealth)
```

To implement the weapons change their damage values using the a class block.

Comment: I would recommend that you import the random module so you can generate a random number for the damage variables and for the stamina reduction.